# How to web scrape with rvest html content which contains a "_ngcontent-c1" tag?

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape html content in R with rvest but some how it doesn't work...

The Html content looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVhEP.png)

I tryed:

```
webpage <- read_html(url)
str(webpage)

raw_data <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*span[@class='club__score']") %>%
  html_text()
raw_data
```

But I don't get any results... does the "_ngcontent-c1"-tag effects my approach? What do I miss?

Comment: do you mean html content?

Comment: Please add `url` from where you want to extract data and show what you want to extract.

Comment: Remove the asterisk in your `xpath`. The `_ngcontent-c1` is just another attribute of the `span`.

Comment: @VigneshA yes, html content - sorry

Comment: @thorepet tried that one befor but doesn't work

Comment: Then please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @RonakShah I am trying to learn web scraping in R. I took this webpage as an example for that: https://www.bundesliga.com/de/statistiken/bundesliga/aktuelle-saison/alle-spieltage/club-statistiken/tore. Object is to get the score of each club.

Comment: The content of this website is provided by JS. Use RSelenium to scrape.